# перевод стандартного ответа "possible duplicate of"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

когда вопрос предлагается закрыть как возможный дубликат, движок добавляет к нему комментарий (от имени предложившего) вида:

```
possible duplicate of <ссылка>
```

[*пример*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438655/#comment459157_438655) такого комментария.

предлагаю перевести это сообщение (варианты в виде ответов).

Comment: Как мне кажется, приведенный вами пример не относится к переводу, так как шаблонных комментариев нет в движке. То есть это желание пользователя использовать английский вариант данного выражения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, комментарий, на который я привёл ссылку, появился автоматически **от моего имени** после того, как я, нажав «удалить», выбрал в диалоге закрытия пункт про дубль и указал ссылку на дубль. движок у меня не спрашивал, хочу ли я формировать такой комментарий вообще, и, тем более, на каком языке я его хочу сформировать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, другие автоматически добавляющиеся от моего имени комментарии (по поводу иных предложенных мною оснований закрытия) содержат текст на русском языке.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, готов стать «подопытным кроликом» для проведения эксперимента: я голосую за закрытие нескольких вопросов под разными предлогами (в том числе «дубль»), и мы смотрим, какие комментарии от моего имени добавит движок. / потом я отменяю свои голоса за закрытие (если получится).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. К сожалению, не вижу данной строки в Transifex. Попробую найти.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, логичнее всего (ставлю себя на место разработчика движка) искать текст таких авто-комментариев где-то поблизости от текстов **причин** закрытия (которые отображаются в диалогах закрытия).

Comment: Исправили недочет. Строка оказалась в настройках. На мой взгляд, можно отметить вариант ответа набравший наиболее количество голов правильным.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, отметил.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возможный дубликат вопроса: `<ссылка>`

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно, этот вопрос здесь уже задавался: **ссылка**

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ: `<ссылка>`

(по мотивам того, что написано в диалоге закрытия).

Comment: Так нельзя, ибо если дубликат обозначен неправильно, а также если помечаются два вопроса от одного автора (а-ля переформулировка), при этом ответов де-факто в вопросах нет, такое предложение будет ложным.

Comment: *а также если помечаются два вопроса от одного автора (а-ля переформулировка)* — кстати, насколько я вижу из опыта использования этого пункта, движок не даст сослаться на вопрос, у которого нет ни принятого, ни с положительным балансом голосов, ответа.

Comment: Дает, если автором обоих вопросов является один и тот же пользователь. Проверял на enSO с месяц назад.

Comment: @Vesper: [*"Вопрос без ответа не может быть отмечен как оригинал дубликата."*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)